# The rings $ F[x,y]/ (y^{2} - x) $ and $F[x,y]/( y^{2} - x^{2}) $ for any field F

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The rings $ F[x,y]/ (y^{2} - x) $ and $F[x,y]/( y^{2} - x^{2})  $ are not isomorphic for any field F.

---

Comment: The second one has zero-divisors $[y-x]$ and $[y+x]$. The first one has none.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? The first one is isomorphic to $F[y]$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126025/isomorphism-kx-y-y-x2-onto-kx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F[x,y](y^2-x) \simeq F[y]$ (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126025/4280) and its answer) and this has no-zero-divisors.

In $F[x,y](y^2-x^2)$ we have zero-divisors $\langle y - x \rangle$ and $\langle y + x \rangle$ (they multiply to $\langle y^2 - x^2 \rangle = 0$).

So the rings cannot be isomorphic.